# HasAndBelongsToMany in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have three Models with the associated properties:

**Links Model:**

```
var $belongsTo = array('LinkCategory');
```

**LinkCategory Model:**

```
var $hasMany = array('Link');
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');
```

**User Model**

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('LinkCategory');
```

With that, I would expect the following to get me all the link categories for the user.

```
$user_link_categories = $this->LinkCategory->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 1)));
```

However, it dies with:
Unknown column 'User.id' in 'where clause'
Query: SELECT `LinkCategory`.`id`, `LinkCategory`.`title`, `LinkCategory`.`created`, `LinkCategory`.`modified` FROM `link_categories` AS `LinkCategory`   WHERE `User`.`id` = 1

I am new to CakePHP, but not MVC. In my mind, this should work given my associations. Have I missed something or does this just not work in CakePHP for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have three Models with the associated properties:
>
> **Links Model**:

There should be **Link** model, not **Links**. I hope that was a misprint.

> **LinkCategory Model**:
>
> ...
>
> var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');

I guess that means that you have join table link_categories_users and therefore you need to change recursive value to 2:

```
$user_link_categories = $this->LinkCategory->find('all', array('recursive' => 2, 'conditions' => array('User.id' => 1)));
```

Or:

```
$user_link_categories = $this->LinkCategory->find('all', array('recursive' => 2, 'conditions' => array('LinkCategoryUser.user_id' => 1)));
```

Or:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('recursive' => 2, 'conditions' => array('User.id' => 1)));
```

***Update***. This *must* work:

```
$user_link_categories = $this->LinkCategory->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 1)));
```

Comment: Really!? Making the query recursive would allow one to filter on `User.id`? Nifty.

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: I'm not sure. That was a guess.

Comment: Yes, this was a misprint. Link is the Model. I also have a join table of link_categories_users. Unforunately, none of the sample code you provided works. Even the last one, which was exceptionally baffling to me.

Comment: I have the similar structure in my application and the last code sample works for me. I've verified it. What is the query log you got?

Comment: I ended up using the `join` parameter as the last code sample does work when the query is left fully recursive. However, this seems overkill as my User model has many additional associations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkCategory` doesn't have a field `User.id`... as a matter of fact, the way `User.id` has a period in the middle suggests `id` is a field which belongs to `User`.

Since `LinkCategory` `belongsTo` a `User` it probably has a field `user_id`, so theoretically this should work:

```
$user_link_categories = $this->LinkCategory->find('all', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => 1)));
```

If this still doesn't work it means your DB tables don't have columns to support these relationships and you'll need to [read more about associations](http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) to get to the bottom of that.

Personally, though, I think you're going backwards. You're trying to find a `LinkCategory` based on their associated `User`, but you can't use a field from another model (`User`) like this in a simple `find()` (on `LinkCategory`).

Instead you should find the User with an `id` of '1', then - since a `User` `belongsTo` a `LinkCategory` - read that's `User`'s `LinkCategory`. Again, I'm rusty, but I'm thinking it would look a little like this...

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Article.id' => 1)));
pr($user);
```

... make that `recursive` (see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/439/recursive)) and `$user` should load your `LinkCategory` as well.

Comment: Also, if you're looking to filter on a field that's in a related model, you should use the Containable property.  You can't tell linkCategory to filter on a property of the Users table, for example, without using Containable.  It's well documented in the manual.

Comment: @Travis Leleu - does that mean what bancer suggests (using `'recursive' => 2`) won't work without `Containable`?

Comment: No, the recursive parameter determines the level of relationships that will be retrieved on a find.  For finer granularity, you can use Containable.  Also, if you want to filter (the conditions parameter) based on fields in the related model, you'll need to use Containable.

Comment: Your code above assumes I have a LinkCategory belongsTo User relationship, and conversely a User hasMany LinkCategory. If you looked at original post, these are HABTM relationships. Thanks anyway.